# Radon-Nikodým property and uncountable basis

Tags: banach-spaces, radon-nikodym, schauder-basis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. It is well-known that if $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a boundedly complete Schauder basis of $X$, then $X$ has the Radon-Nikodým property (indeed, $X$ is separable and is canonically isomorphic to $H^*$, where $H$ is the closed linear span of the coordinate functionals associated to $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$).

Now assume that $X$ has an uncountable (unconditional) boundedly complete basis $(x_i)_{i \in I}$. By an unconditional basis I mean a family $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ with the property that for every $x \in X$, there exists a unique family of scalaras $(\alpha_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $x = \sum_{i \in I} \alpha_i x_i$, and the sum is meant in the sense that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a finite subset $F$ of $I$ such that
$$\left\| x - \sum_{i \in G} \alpha_i x_i\right\| < \varepsilon$$
whenever $G$ is a finite subset of $I$ that contains $F$.

Under such conditions, does $X$ also have the Radon-Nikodým property?

Comment: The definition of a (Schauder) basis in a Banach space requires it to be countable, so your question has no meaning in that context.

Comment: By an unconditional (generalized) basis of $X$ I mean a family $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ (not necessarily countable) with the property that for every $x \in X$, there exists a unique family of scalars $(\alpha_i)_{i \in I}$ such that $x = \sum_{i \in I} a_i x_i$. This sum is meant in the sense that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a finite subset $F$ of $I$ such that $\|x - \sum_{i \in G} a_i x_i\| < \varepsilon$ whenever $G$ is a finite subset of $I$ that contains $F$.

Comment: What you wrote now has almost no connection to your original question.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more clear. Sorry